# how to populate 2D array with user input from two text boxes

Tags: arrays, vb.net, textbox

I have two `text boxes` on the form with two `buttons` (one button is **add** and the other is **close**) in vb.net.

Both text boxes text are integers.

When user enters data in the text boxes then click on close it populates an array.
Upto this point its working fine.

This is my code part:

```
Dim sundp As Object(,) = New Object(25, 1) {}

For l1 As Integer = 0 To 25

            sundp(l1, 0) = frm1.TextBox1.Text
            sundp(l1, 1) = frm1.TextBox2.Text
Next
```

When comes to add button, if the user clicks on add button, it should add text from text boxes as 1st item of the array and clear the contents and ready for user input as 2nd item of array and so on. How can I do it?.

Comment: you want to clear the textbox's after adding and want to continue the same addition upto 25 element ah?

Comment: Use a jagged array (`Object()()`) instead of a multi-dimensional array (`Object(,)`), look it up to see why.

Answer (score 1):

Good attempt so far.  However, you are using the wrong hammer.  A loop is the wrong construct as you can't break and wait for user input.  This looks like Winforms, which uses an event-driven model.

Something like this should work:

'form-level variable

```
Private sundp As Object(,) = New Object(25, 1) {}
Private sundpIndex As Int32 = 0
```

'button click handler:

```
sundp(sundpIndex, 0) = frm1.TextBox1.Text
sundp(sundpIndex, 1) = frm1.TextBox2.Text
frm1.TextBox1.Text = String.Empty
frm1.TextBox2.Text = String.Empty
sundpIndex += 1

If 24 <= sundpIndex Then
  ' you've reached your 25 element maximum, do something appropriate.
End If
```

Comment: thanks for reply. this code works as the same way as close button works as i explained. It only adds one item only.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Finally, i succeeded in working as i expected. thanks for your help.

Answer (score -3):

Instead of arrays, use sql table to store the values of your textboxes. because whenever you click the button, the arrays will get cleared because it works only for runtime.

```
sub btn_click()
{
dim cmd as new sqlcommand("insert into tbl values('" & frm1.TextBox1.Text & "','" & frm1.TextBox2.Text & "')",conn)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
frm1.TextBox1.Text=""
frm1.TextBox2.Text=""
}
```

Comment: -1. I don't think SQL is in scope for this problem. It's like - oh, you need a car, sure no problem, go buy a car factory and build one for yourself there.

Comment: In addition to SQL not being relevant for the question, your statement about arrays isn't relevant. Of course the array is wiped at runtime; the user is not asking about persisting the data. They are asking about how to individually add new items to the array. It's really a user interface question.